# how can I see the cpu useage in a slurm job

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm

Is there a way to monitor the % of cpu useage in a cluster using slurm.
For example imagine I have 200 nodes, and I send an mpi work that use all those 200 nodes, it could be that only one node is been used(really calculating stuff) while the other are not.
Is there an option that tell me - average cpu load in the 200 nodes, or current cpu load on every one of the cpus?

**EDIT: on a BlueGene machine**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The slurm command:

```
sstat "jobid"
```

replace "jobid" with your integer jobid.

It will return several columns including 'AveCPU' & 'AveDiskRead'

Comment: Thanks, but I get: 
sstat: error: The sstat command is not supported on IBM BlueGene systems